# Tflite TOCO conversion failed for K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using toco_convert of tensorflow lite for some old work.
These are the errors I am getting for the following commands.

```
toco\
--graph_def_file=6-graphmh-55epoc.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/leaves.tflite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=ImageTensor \
--output_arrays=SemanticPredictions \
--input_shapes=1,113,3 \
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\diec\Scripts\toco_from_protos-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\ash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\diec\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\toco\python\toco_from_protos.py", line 59, in main
    app.run(main=execute, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\ash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\diec\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\ash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\diec\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\toco\python\toco_from_protos.py", line 33, in execute
    output_str = tensorflow_wrap_toco.TocoConvert(model_str, toco_str, input_str)
Exception: We are continually in the process of adding support to TensorFlow Lite for more ops. It would be helpful if you could inform us of how this conversion went by opening a github issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?template=40-tflite-op-request.md
 and pasting the following:

Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime. If those are native TensorFlow operators, you might be able to use the extended runtime by passing --enable_select_tf_ops, or by setting target_ops=TFLITE_BUILTINS,SELECT_TF_OPS when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Otherwise, if you have a custom implementation for them you can disable this error with --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of builtin operators you are using: ADD, EXP, FULLY_CONNECTED, LOGISTIC, MUL. Here is a list of operators for which you will need custom implementations: RandomStandardNormal.
```

I know that tf.lite.toco_convert is depricated, but I need it for old works.
I think it is due to the following line
`epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon`.
I am not sure why is this happening, cuz the old tensorflow keras.backend has `random_normal` attribute.
It would be helpful if you can debug or point to some resources to circumvent this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended approach :

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                        tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

The conversion :

```
toco\
--graph_def_file=6-graphmh-55epoc.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/leaves.tflite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=ImageTensor \
--output_arrays=SemanticPredictions \
--input_shapes=1,256,3 \
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from here : https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                        tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

It is because `RandomStandardNormal` is not part of TensorFlow lite, so we need to use `tf.lite.OpsSet` to include it